# Extract Aggregator values in Batch Execution

Tags: java, batch-processing, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there any way to programatically extract the final value of the aggregators after a Dataflow batch execution ?

Based on the [DirectePipelineRunner](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DirectPipelineRunner) class, I wrote the following method. It seems to work, but for dinamically created counters, it gives different values than the values shown in the console output.

PS. If it helps, I'm assuming that aggregators are based on Long values, with a sum combining function.

```
public static Map<String, Object> extractAllCounters(Pipeline p, PipelineResult pr)
{
    AggregatorPipelineExtractor aggregatorExtractor = new AggregatorPipelineExtractor(p);
    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Aggregator<?, ?>, Collection<PTransform<?, ?>>> e :
            aggregatorExtractor.getAggregatorSteps().entrySet()) {
        Aggregator agg = e.getKey();
        try {
            results.put(agg.getName(), pr.getAggregatorValues(agg).getTotalValue(agg.getCombineFn()));
        } catch(AggregatorRetrievalException|IllegalArgumentException aggEx) {
            //System.err.println("Can't extract " + agg.getName() + ": " + aggEx.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of aggregators should be available in the `PipelineResult`. For example:

```
CountOddsFn countOdds = new CountOddsFn();
pipeline
  .apply(Create.of(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 20, 42, 68, 100))
  .apply(ParDo.of(countOdds));
PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
// Here you may need to use the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner 

AggregatorValues<Integer> values =
result.getAggregatorValues(countOdds.aggregator);
Map<String, Integer> valuesAtSteps = values.getValuesAtSteps();
// Now read the values from the step...
```

Example `DoFn` that reports the aggregator:

```
private static class CountOddsFn extends DoFn<Integer, Void> {

  Aggregator<Integer, Integer> aggregator =
    createAggregator("odds", new SumIntegerFn());

  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    if (c.element() % 2 == 1) {
      aggregator.addValue(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like a more general solution like I posted, but this is fine